# Do "finché" (and "fino a che") mean "until" or "as long as" (or both)?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

I know we're not supposed to ask questions that can be looked up in a dictionary here, but I have already looked up dictionaries, read blog posts and forum discussions, all of which have just confused me even more. So I just hope someone can clarify this for me. Please bear with me as I try to explain where exactly my confusion is.

First, I want to point something out. The expressions *as long as* and *until*, with regards to time, are both ways to specify the time period during which an event occurs with respect to another event. Other than this, they are complements (or negations) of each other. Since when I say *A as long as B*, I'm implying that the time of A intersects with the time of B. But when I say *A until B* I'm implying that the time of A *does not* intersect the time of B.

According to [this blog post](https://italian.yabla.com/lesson-Finch%C3%A9-as-long-as-and-Finch%C3%A9-non-until-1008), *finché* just means *as long as*, and *finché non* means *until*, which would make perfect sense given what I mentioned above. In fact, I don't see the point of having a separate definition for *finché non* when that can be deduced from the definition of *finché*. That post also mentions that *finché* is sometimes, mistakenly used to mean *until* (but I guess *finché non* is never used to mean *as long as*). I even checked some translations of *finché* using [reverso context](https://context.reverso.net/translation/italian-english/finch%C3%A9) and I see that it's in fact used both ways. But if I trust the blog post above, most of these Italian writers are just using it wrong (or colloquially).

That seemed good enough, but then I remembered the expression *fino a che*. I read somewhere that *finché* is just a shorter way to say *fino a che*. But when I translate this in Google, it says *until*. That's *finché non*, it's negation. So then I looked up *fino a che* on [reverso context](https://context.reverso.net/translation/italian-english/fino+a+che) and saw that it's also used both ways!

*Speri fino a che il tuo avversario si stanchi.* = *You wait until your opponent tires.*

but also

*Lo sarò fino a che potrò.* = *I'll be one for as long as I can.*

So either these Italian writers are also using it wrong, or the blog post above is wrong. I'm starting to believe that both *finché* and *fino a che* can actually (and correctly) mean both *as long as* and *until*, and the only way to tell one from another is by looking at the context. My current understanding is that *A finché B* means *A until B* if B is an instantaneous event, like that start or end of something. And it means as *A long as B* when B is something that happen over a period of time.

So I guess to summarize, my questions are:

1. Can I use *finché* every time I'd use *fino a che*?
2. Can I use *fino a che* every time I'd use *finché*?
3. Is the blog post I mentioned correct in that *finché* only means *as long as* although it is sometimes mistakenly used to mean *until*?
4. If the answer to the above question is no, then is my current understanding of how to tell one meaning from another any good?

Comment: “Speri fino a che il tuo avversario si stanchi” sounds quite weird in Italian, possibly an automatic translation artefact. Do we know the source (not reverso, but who actually wrote it, if anyone)? Anyway, the short, partial answer – until I or someone else writes a real, complete one – is that, even though in past times the meanings were kept distinct (_finché_ / _finché non_), nowadays _finché_ can mean both, depending on the context. Both _lavoro finché ne ho voglia_ (“as long as”) and _lavoro finché arriva Mario_ (“until”) are usual, correct Italian sentences.

Comment: See for instance, if you haven't already done so, https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/finche

Comment: @DaG Unfortunately I don't think they will give you the source. But there are a few other examples on the links I posted. There's also an option to see examples in which the word is used as "until" and other in which it's used as "as long as".

Comment: As an aside, in Italian “You wait until your opponent tires” would be something like _Aspetti che il tuo avversario si stanchi_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treccani dictionary defines [*finché*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/finche) as:

> Fino a che, fino a tanto che, fino a quando; indica il perdurare di una cosa o di un fatto per tutto il tempo in cui dura un’altra cosa o un altro fatto o non se ne verifica uno nuovo; generalmente usato con il modo indic.: *f. c’è vita c’è speranza; restate f. volete; gridò fin che ebbe fiato in corpo; E tu onore di pianti, Ettore, avrai ... f. il Sole Risplenderà su le sciagure umane* (Foscolo). In frasi negative indica invece che una cosa non può o non deve accadere fino al momento in cui non se ne verifica un’altra: *non ti muovere f. non lo dico io; non aprì f. non l’ebbe riconosciuto.*

So, it seems to confirm that *finché* would correspond to “as long as” (the contemporaneity of two actions of situations), while *finché non* would correspond to “until” (one successive to the other ones), and this is the traditional view.

However, other dictionaries adopt a somewhat more modern (and realistic) approach. De Mauro's dictionary, for instance, admits both uses of [*finché*](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/finche), and even says (my translation): “the adverb *non* may or may not be present, while the meaning does not change”:

> fino a quando, fino al momento in cui, in proposizioni temporali all’indicativo o al congiuntivo in cui può essere presente o meno l’avv. *non* senza che il significato cambi: *aspetterò qui finché non torni, finché andavano a scuola erano buoni amici, puoi stare con noi finché vorrai*; fino al punto in cui: *siamo andati avanti finché la strada si è interrotta*

The more traditional, and quite authoritative, Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana also includes both meanings. You can see the [complete article](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00001031.jpg), but just to give two examples from good writers:

> “as long as”: Finché hai dardi, scàgliali! (D'Annunzio)
>
> “until”: Rimase a guardare ritto finché la luce disparve. (Comisso)

So, context is actually the only guide.

As for possible differences between *finché* and *fino a che*, as an Italian I don't find any, besides the exigences of a sentence's euphony. More to the point, dictionaries seem to agree in treating both the one-word form and the split form together: Treccani and GDLI (above) define *finché* as “Fino a che [and so on]”; furthermore, Treccani, in its article about [*fino*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fino2/), puts together “*fino a che* o *fin che* o *finché*”; see also [“Finché or fin che?”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/finche-o-fin-che_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/).

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. A weird thing I've noted is that Google Translator does seem to be able to correctly tell one meaning from another, at least for every sentence I've translated so far, so there must be some objective, "mechanical" way to distinguish the actual meaning given the context.

Comment: @Juan: Yes, it's called deep learning. :)

Comment: @Juan: I may confirm that it seems to distinguish _mangia finché sei sazio_ from _mangia finché sei affamato_, but of course the two sentences can be distinguished only using semantic means, i.e. “knowing” what _sazio_ and _affamato_ mean. For another example how could you tell apart the possible meanings of _XXX finché sono a Roma_ (“XXX until/as long as I'm in Rome”), not knowing the meaning of the rest of the sentence, or of an even wider context?

Comment: Nice examples! Also *aspetta finché sei affamato* is translated as *wait until you are hungry*, which I guess it also makes sense, so it's a bit like your Rome example. Guess I'll just have to deep learn my way through Italian :)

Comment: @Juan I personally do not trust google translator. May be sometimes it be very smart, but you can never tell. I've found many horrible translations there, using different languages.